Android Studio Generate Signed Bundle or APK task :app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets run forever
i have proble when clone a project by React Native
when generate apk file task :app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets run forever
Anyone can help me ?
I run it many times. Retart window.Delete nodes_modules but it's not sucessfully
enter image description here

Please do not post errors as image, instead copy and paste on SO. Thank you
